# Can I disable print dialogs in ngxPrint?

Tags: angular, printing

I want to disable the print dialogs. I am using ngx-print, is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@media print {
  #print-section {
    display : none!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand.... I am still new to using angular and ngxprint, please elaborate

Comment: Add this code to your css file